# c# solving task using recursion

Tags: c#, function, recursion

This is data (module code, subject, how many subjects you have to take in order to attend this module, that module(s) code(s)

```
N01 Math 0
N02 Physics 1 N01
N03 Chemistry 2 N01 N02
N04 Sports 0
N05 Logic 1 N04
N06 Music 1 N05
N07 Theatre 2 N03 N06
N08 Law 1 N03
N09 OS 2 N07 N08
```

Final results

```
N01 Math
N04 Sports
N02 Physics
N03 Chemistry
N08 Law
N05 Logic
N06 Music
N07 Theatre
N09 OS
```

Task: Find all modules, which meets the requirements for example (Math and sports dont have any requirements, so they are first and second, in order to take physics, you have to take math, which doesnt have any requirements, so physics is third and so on.)

I have to use recursion to solve this problem, but I don't know where to start, what is stack, I only know how to solve simple problems using recursion, like finding factorial. Any tips or guidelines how to solve this problem?

Comment: Are you allowed to ask for help for this assignment? Also, just start with parsing the data, and get an overview of what you have. You shouldn't panick with no lines of code!

Comment: Yes. I parsed all data into array. But I don't know how to use recursion.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to give you any code, because that is *your* job. But to give you an idea what to do:

You need a data structure that has

- ID (`string`)
- Name (`string`)
- Dependencies (`List<string>`)

You get your data into a list of those.

You can then write a function, let's call it `CalcDependencyLevel` that calculates the dependency level of each data structure compared to the list of structures:

This method checks the dependencies. If no dependencies, it's 0. If it has one dependency, it's 1 + the result of `CalcDependencyLevel` for that dependency (this is the recursion).

If something has multiple dependencies, you need to calculate all results and then use the maximum.

Attach this score to each data structure and then order by that score.

If you want to optimize your algorithm, attach the score to the structure as soon as you calculate it and use the precalculated score in your recursion if available, so you don't have to recalculate it for the same instance over and over.

---

A rough implementation of what I said above (probably more advanced than your class is right now, you should definitely go and implement your solution with the means you *know*, not just copy this and turn it in):

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp14
{
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;

    internal class Course
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public List<string> Dependencies { get; set; }

        public int? DependencyDepth { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Name;
        }
    }

    internal class Program
    {
        private static string data = "N01 Math 0\n" 
                                   + "N02 Physics 1 N01\n"
                                   + "N03 Chemistry 2 N01 N02\n"
                                   + "N04 Sports 0\n"
                                   + "N05 Logic 1 N04\n"
                                   + "N06 Music 1 N05\n"
                                   + "N07 Theatre 2 N03 N06\n"
                                   + "N08 Law 1 N03\n"
                                   + "N09 OS 2 N07 N08\n";

        private static int DependencyDepth(Course course, List<Course> courses)
        {
            if (!course.DependencyDepth.HasValue)
            {
                if (!course.Dependencies.Any())
                {
                    course.DependencyDepth = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    course.DependencyDepth = 1 + course.Dependencies.Max(dep => DependencyDepth(courses.First(c => c.Id == dep), courses));
                }
            }

            return course.DependencyDepth.Value;
        }

        static void Main()
        {
            var courses = data.Split("\n", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                              .Select(line => line.Split(" "))
                              .Select(parts => new Course { Id = parts[0], Name = parts[1], Dependencies = parts.Skip(3).ToList() })
                              .ToList();

            courses.ForEach(course => DependencyDepth(course, courses));

            courses.OrderBy(course => course.DependencyDepth).ToList().ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
            
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

---

The result is

> Math
>
> Sports
>
> Physics
>
> Logic
>
> Chemistry
>
> Music
>
> Theatre
>
> Law
>
> OS

Logic *only* needs sports. I have no idea why your goal is to get Chemistry sorted in *before* Logic as it relies on two other levels of courses. You may want to ask how your expected results came to be. They don't add up.